# Submit button becomes invisible after speech input (Web Speech API)

Tags: user-interface, chatbot, speech-to-text, webspeech-api

This code contains the user interface of the banking chatbot. I have used Mozilla's Web Speech API to implement the speech to text feature. After implementing it, I have faced a major bug. As soon as the user starts the speech recognition by clicking on the "Speak" button; the textarea automatically increases in size and covers or hides the Submit button which is preventing the user from submitting his/her query. I haven't been able to locate the error.

```js
//initialize speech recognition API
window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

const recognition = new SpeechRecognition(); //initialize my instance of speech recognition
recognition.interimResults = true; //return results while still working on current recognition

//this is where your speech-to-text results will appear
let p = document.createElement("p")
const words = document.querySelector(".words-container")
words.appendChild(p)

//I want to select and change the color of the body, but this could be any HTML element on your page
let body = document.querySelector("body")

let cap_css_colors = ["AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Azure","Beige","Bisque","Black","BlanchedAlmond","Blue","BlueViolet","Brown","BurlyWood","CadetBlue","Chartreuse","Chocolate","Coral","CornflowerBlue","Cornsilk","Crimson","Cyan","DarkBlue","DarkCyan","DarkGoldenRod","DarkGray","DarkGrey","DarkGreen","DarkKhaki","DarkMagenta","DarkOliveGreen","Darkorange","DarkOrchid","DarkRed","DarkSalmon","DarkSeaGreen","DarkSlateBlue","DarkSlateGray","DarkSlateGrey","DarkTurquoise","DarkViolet","DeepPink","DeepSkyBlue","DimGray","DimGrey","DodgerBlue","FireBrick","FloralWhite","ForestGreen","Fuchsia","Gainsboro","GhostWhite","Gold","GoldenRod","Gray","Grey","Green","GreenYellow","HoneyDew","HotPink","IndianRed","Indigo","Ivory","Khaki","Lavender","LavenderBlush","LawnGreen","LemonChiffon","LightBlue","LightCoral","LightCyan","LightGoldenRodYellow","LightGray","LightGrey","LightGreen","LightPink","LightSalmon","LightSeaGreen","LightSkyBlue","LightSlateGray","LightSlateGrey","LightSteelBlue","LightYellow","Lime","LimeGreen","Linen","Magenta","Maroon","MediumAquaMarine","MediumBlue","MediumOrchid","MediumPurple","MediumSeaGreen","MediumSlateBlue","MediumSpringGreen","MediumTurquoise","MediumVioletRed","MidnightBlue","MintCream","MistyRose","Moccasin","NavajoWhite","Navy","OldLace","Olive","OliveDrab","Orange","OrangeRed","Orchid","PaleGoldenRod","PaleGreen","PaleTurquoise","PaleVioletRed","PapayaWhip","PeachPuff","Peru","Pink","Plum","PowderBlue","Purple","Red","RosyBrown","RoyalBlue","SaddleBrown","Salmon","SandyBrown","SeaGreen","SeaShell","Sienna","Silver","SkyBlue","SlateBlue","SlateGray","SlateGrey","Snow","SpringGreen","SteelBlue","Tan","Teal","Thistle","Tomato","Turquoise","Violet","Wheat","White","WhiteSmoke","Yellow","YellowGreen"];
const CSS_COLORS = cap_css_colors.map(color => {
  //I need to change all color names to lower case, because comparison between words will be case sensitive
  return color.toLowerCase()
})

//once speech recognition determines it has a "result", grab the texts of that result, join all of them, and add to paragraph
recognition.addEventListener("result", e => {
  const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
  .map(result => result[0])
  .map(result => result.transcript)
  .join("")
  p.innerText = transcript

  //once speech recognition determines it has a final result, create a new paragraph and append it to the words-container
  //this way every time you add a new p to hold your speech-to-text every time you're finished with the previous results
  if (e.results[0].isFinal) {
    p = document.createElement("p")
    words.appendChild(p)
  }
  //for each result, map through all color names and check if current result (transcript) contains that color
  //i.e. see if a person said any color name you know
  CSS_COLORS.forEach(color => {
    //if find a match, change your background color to that color
    if (transcript.includes(color)) {
      body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
  }) 
})

//add your functionality to the start and stop buttons
function startRecording() {
  recognition.start();
  recognition.addEventListener("end", recognition.start)

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopRecording)
}

function stopRecording() {
  console.log("okay I'll stop")
  recognition.removeEventListener("end", recognition.start)
  recognition.stop();
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    color: #444;
}

button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.page-description {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tz-link {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #1da7da;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.no-browser-support {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #e64427;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.app {
    margin: 40px auto;
}

#note-textarea {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#recording-instructions {
    margin: 15px auto 60px;
}

#notes {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.note .header {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: #888;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.note .delete-note,
.note .listen-note {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.note .content {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        padding: 50px 25px;
    }

    button {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

}   



/* -- Demo ads -- */

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    #bsaHolder{ display:none;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MJ BOT </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <section class="msger">
    <header class="msger-header">
      <div class="msger-header-title">
        <i class=""></i> MJ Chatbot <i class=""></i>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main class="msger-chat">
      <div class="msg left-msg">
        <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145867.svg)"></div>

        <div class="msg-bubble">
          <div class="msg-info">
            <div class="msg-info-name"></div>
           </div>
         
          <div class="msg-text">
         <p>  {{ questionAsked }} </p>
             </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       
     
    </main>
    <article>
     <main class="msger-chat">
      <div class="msg right-msg">     
        <div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/327/327779.svg)"></div>

        <div class="msg-bubble">
          <div class="msg-info">
            <div class="msg-info-name"></div>
           </div>
        
          <div class="msg-text">
         <p>  {{ response }}</p>
             </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>


    </main>

    <form id="output" class="msger-inputarea" action="signup" method="post">
  <input  id="output" class="msger-input" type="text" name="question"></input>
 
  <input  id='play' class="msger-send-btn" type="submit" value="Submit Message !" > </input>

 <input  type="button"  value="Speak" onclick="runSpeechRecognition()"></input> &nbsp; 
    
    <button id='stop'></button>
  </form>

   
   
 <button id=play style="font-size:24px">Listen <i class="fas fa-file-audio"></i></button>&nbsp;


      
    

    <a href="{{ url_for('contact')}}">Send Query to Agent !</a>

  
  </section>
<script >onload = function() {
    if ('speechSynthesis' in window) with(speechSynthesis) {


        var playEle = document.querySelector('#play');
        var pauseEle = document.querySelector('#pause');
        var stopEle = document.querySelector('#stop');
        var flag = false;


        playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
        pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
        stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

        function onClickPlay() {
            if(!flag){
                flag = true;
                utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('article').textContent);
                utterance.voice = getVoices()[0];
                utterance.onend = function(){
                    flag = false; playEle.className = pauseEle.className = ''; stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                };
                playEle.className = 'played';
                stopEle.className = '';
                speak(utterance);
            }
             if (paused) { /* unpause/resume narration */
                playEle.className = 'played';
                pauseEle.className = '';
                resume();
            } 
        }

        function onClickPause() {
            if(speaking && !paused){ /* pause narration */
                pauseEle.className = 'paused';
                playEle.className = '';
                pause();
            }
        }

        function onClickStop() {
            if(speaking){ /* stop narration */
                /* for safari */
                stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
                flag = false;
                cancel();

            }
        }

    }

    else { /* speech synthesis not supported */
        msg = document.createElement('h5');
        msg.textContent = "Detected no support for Speech Synthesis";
        msg.style.textAlign = 'center';
        msg.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        msg.style.color = 'white';
        msg.style.marginTop = msg.style.marginBottom = 0;
        document.body.insertBefore(msg, document.querySelector('div'));
    }

}
</script>
  <script>
      /* JS comes here */
        function runSpeechRecognition() {
            // get output div reference
            var output = document.getElementById("output");
            // get action element reference
            var action = document.getElementById("help");
                // new speech recognition object
                var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
                var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
            
                // This runs when the speech recognition service starts
                recognition.onstart = function() {
                    action.innerHTML = "<small>listening, please speak...</small>";
                };
                
                recognition.onspeechend = function() {
                    action.innerHTML = "<small>stopped listening, hope you are done...</small>";
                    recognition.stop();
                }
              
                // This runs when the speech recognition service returns result
                recognition.onresult = function(event) {
                    var transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                    var confidence = event.results[0][0].confidence;
                    output.innerHTML = "<b></b> " + transcript + "<br/> <b></b> " ;
                    output.classList.remove("hide");
                };
              
                 // start recognition
                 recognition.start();
          }
    </script>
  
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js'></script>
 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recognition.onend = (event) => {
 //insert your code to display button here
}
```